# Safari parent javascript function

Tags: javascript, iframe

Im having a strange issue only in safari browser, im calling a parent window's javascript function from within a child iframe. 
Initially the iframe's src will be an external site which will redirect to my site after the work is done. The redirect page contains the following three lines of code.

This seems to work in all browsers except safari.

The only call within the iframe is

```
<script>
self.parent.PARENT_FUNCTION("param");
</script>
```

Ive tried several other ways instead of self.parent like top.PARENT_FUNCTION,etc but still the main window's location seems to change.

One thing we noticed is that while the redirect is happening within the iframe, im getting a security certificate warning, once I clieck continue, then the browsers location changes to the new redirect url instead of just the iframe's src.

any clues what could the issue be ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the issue is with safari browser and invalid security certificate of the site within the iframe. 
It basically does a frame busting and changes the main window's url if the site within the iframe is having an invalid ceritificate.